# Configure a sitecore role to access the system folder

Tags: security, sitecore

i'm using Sitecore 6.5.
I want to configure a Sitecore role to access the /system folder from the content editor.
(my end goal is to have certain user to access and edit the webforms in /system/modules/web forms for marketeers)

I have granted read rights to the system folder on the role, but the /system folder does not appear in the content editor tree.

I guess if there is some other security preventing the users to see the system folder?
I can only get a view on the system folder by granting full admin rights to the user.

Answer (score 15):

First off, make sure the user has the `Entire Tree` and `Hidden Items` options ticked in the `View` tab.

Also, to check if it's access rights you can use the `Access Viewer` to see whether the user has access rights. If they don't you can click on the `Read` right (for instance) and see why they don't have access to the System node (for example, which role `Denies` the read access).

For more information, please check the [Security Reference document on SDN](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Security%20Reference.aspx).

Comment: Where is the `View` tab?

Comment: It's in the Content Editor

Comment: The trick to getting the View tab to show is adding the user to the Content Developing role.

Comment: Can these application settings be applied on a role level?

Comment: @BenSewards As far as I know, not by default, but with a bit of custom code I'm sure that could be accomplished. John West had a blog post on something similar (setting application options when logging in): http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2012/12/Automatically-Show-the-Quick-Info-Section-in-the-Content-Editor-of-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx